# Airflow external_task_sensor never stops poking

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I need to wait for another task in another dag until I can trigger my own task. But my external sensor is not stopping poking. I already read some of the other related questions here and made sure I have adjusted the execution_delta. But still, I have the same issue.

Here are my two dags

Parent Dag:

```
import datetime
import pendulum
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Europe/Berlin")
args = {
    "start_date": datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 25, tzinfo=local_tz),
    "provide_context": True,
}

def start_job(process_name, **kwargs):
    print('do something: ' + process_name)
    return True


with models.DAG(
        dag_id="test_parent",
        default_args=args,
        # catchup=False,
) as dag:

    task_parent_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_parent_1",
        python_callable=start_job,
        op_kwargs={"process_name": "my parent task 1"},
        provide_context=True,
    )

    task_parent_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_parent_2",
        python_callable=start_job,
        op_kwargs={"process_name": "my parent task 2"},
        provide_context=True,
    )

    task_parent_1 >> task_parent_2
```

And my child dag:

```
import datetime
import pendulum
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import ExternalTaskSensor

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Europe/Berlin")
args = {
    "start_date": datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 25, tzinfo=local_tz),
    "provide_context": True,
}


def start_job(process_name, **kwargs):
    print('do something: ' + process_name)
    return True


with models.DAG(
        dag_id="test_child",
        default_args=args,
        # catchup=False,
) as dag:
    wait_for_parent_task = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_parent_task',
        external_dag_id='test_parent',
        external_task_id='task_parent_2',
        execution_delta=datetime.timedelta(hours=24),
        # execution_date_fn=lambda dt: dt - datetime.timedelta(hours=24),
    )

    task_child_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_child_1",
        python_callable=start_job,
        op_kwargs={"process_name": "my child task 1"},
        provide_context=True,
    )

    task_child_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_child_2",
        python_callable=start_job,
        op_kwargs={"process_name": "my child task 2"},
        provide_context=True,
    )

    task_child_1 >> wait_for_parent_task >> task_child_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code-wise it looks correct, but the start_date is set to today. With `execution_delta` set, the `ExternalTaskSensor` will check for the task with execution date `execution_date - execution_delta`. I.e. the first DAG run will start on the 26th at 00:00, and the `ExternalTaskSensor` will check for a task with execution_date of 25th 00:00 - 24 hours = 24th 00:00. Since that's before your DAG's starting date, there won't be a task for that execution_date.

In the logs you should see the DAG/task/date it's checking: `Poking for tasks %s in dag %s on %s ...`. You could set your DAG's starting date to a few days ago or let it run for a few days to debug the issue.

Comment: THX @Bas. I was actually misinterpreting the execution_delta. I hoped it mean: Any success since "execution_date - execution_delta" up to now. Is it possible to check a time range instead of an exact time point?

Comment: Not a range, but checking a list of timedeltas is possible using `execution_date_fn`. See an example here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/tests/sensors/test_external_task_sensor.py#L228

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I found also a way that worked for me by setting the execution date to the scheduled date of the parent dag. The advantage: you can trigger the dag also manually

Assuming that the parent dag is scheduled at 6.00 AM in the timezone "Europe/Berlin".

```
    wait_for_parent_task = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_parent_task ',
        external_dag_id='test_parent',
        external_task_id='task_parent_2',
        check_existence=True,
        # execution_date needs to be exact (scheduled time) and the london timezone
        # Remember: The scheduled start is always the one step further in the past - 
        # For a daily schedule: - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        execution_date_fn=lambda dt: (datetime.datetime(year=dt.year, month=dt.month, day=dt.day, tzinfo=local_tz)
                                      + datetime.timedelta(hours=6, minutes=0)
                                      - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                                      ).astimezone(local_tz_london),
    )
```